# Simple Encoder utilizes String.Replace() method

Tags: c#, string, replace, wpf-controls, messagebox

I am writing some software that takes a given string and replaces the letters to create sort of a "code".  Here is my code to do that:

```
string v = this.EncodeInput.ToString().ToUpper();

string result = v.Replace("A","s")
                 .Replace("B", "y")
                 .Replace("C", "t")
                 .Replace("D", "g")
                 .Replace("E", "c")
                 .Replace("F", "x")
                 .Replace("G", "v")
                 .Replace("H", "e")
                 .Replace("I", "d")
                 .Replace("J", "l")
                 .Replace("K", "n")
                 .Replace("L", "k")
                 .Replace("M", "0")
                 .Replace("N", "1")
                 .Replace("O", "9")
                 .Replace("P", "a")
                 .Replace("Q", "q")
                 .Replace("R", "2")
                 .Replace("S", "z")
                 .Replace("T", "5")
                 .Replace("U", "w")
                 .Replace("V", "f")
                 .Replace("W", "7")
                 .Replace("X", "6")
                 .Replace("Y", "4")
                 .Replace("Z", "m")
                 .Replace("1", "j")
                 .Replace("2", "3")
                 .Replace("3", "r")
                 .Replace("4", "h")
                 .Replace("5", "u")
                 .Replace("6", "0")
                 .Replace("7", "8")
                 .Replace("8", "i")
                 .Replace("9", "p")
                 .Replace("0", "b");
```

I believe that that is okay.  Then, I am trying to display the output of that in a MessageBox.  Here is that code:

```
MessageBox.Show(result);
```

That works...  kind of.  The box shows up just fine, but it is full of gibberish.  Here is what it outputs for an input of "A":

[image: Message Box]

I cannot figure out why-- it should output "s".  It shows that exact same string of characters regardless of what goes in the input.  For example, I could input "Hello", and it would show the same thing.

Here is my reporting XAML:

```
<TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="20,79,20,56" Name="EncodeInput"/>
            <Button HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="78" Height="25" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,0,20,15" Content="Encode Now"  Click="Encode_It"/>
```

In other words, why is the gibberish showing up, and not my variable?

Comment: Um it will. If `EncodeInput` is truly `"A"`

Comment: Why do you have this tagged ASP.NET. `MessageBox` is from Windows Forms.

Comment: Run this in the debgguger. What is the value of `this.EncodeInput`?

Comment: John--  Whoops!  That was a typo.  Thank you!

Comment: So EncodeInput is a function, not a property? Or a property that works with data in class scope. Need to see code to help.

Comment: UPDATE:  I named the wrong TextBox "EncodeInput".  It is now replacing correctly, but that string of gibberish is still appended to the front of it.

Comment: I would recommend you to refine your question as it is kinda confusing. Thanks and regards,

Comment: GroverBoy--  "EncodeInput"  is the name of a TextBox.  See XAML code above.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is intended, but see this: `.Replace("M", "0")`... Further down the code, `.Replace("0", "b");`... So "M" ends up as "b" instead of "0"... Is this intended?

Comment: Rshepp--  I had not even considered that.  That would really mess things up.  Thank you very much!!!

Comment: You also have both 'M' and '6' mapped to '0'. One of them should be 'o' instead...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct the syntax as shown below (assuming that `EncodeInput` is the name of `TextBox`):

```
string v = this.EncodeInput.Text.ToUpper();
```

Thanks and regards,